# Google Drive Custom file Properties limitation

Tags: google-drive-api, custom-properties

Is someone please explain the meaning of "totaled from all sources" which described at below
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/properties

> Maximum of 100 custom properties per file, totaled from all sources.
> Maximum of 30 public properties per file, totaled from all sources.
> Maximum of 30 private properties per file from any one application.

My intention is to store over 30 properties at drive file and can be able to search with all shared user.
Is it possible to do it with drive properties api?

Comment: Please share more details. Is this in any way related to programming?

Comment: @NicoHaase it's not related with programming and it's related with google drive api. For now in public properties, google drive only accept 30 custom properties per file but I want to insert properties to each file over 30 custom properties. So, I just find out is there any way to do so.

Comment: If this is not related to programming, this question is off-topic here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`totaled from all sources` refers to any property that has been added to the file, irrespective of which app was used for this.

That is, a file can have up to:

- 30 public properties (that is, visible to all apps) (field `properties`).
- 30 private properties per app (field `appProperties`).
- 100 properties in total (counting public and private properties).

That is, you can have **30 public `properties`** plus **30 `appProperties` per app**, with a **total maximum of 100**.

When those limits are reached, the API returns the following error message:

> The file's property and app property limit has been reached. Files can have up to 30 properties and 30 app properties per app, with a maximum of 100 in total.

#### Reference:

- [File resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. After added 30 public custom properties, it shows like above your mentioned error message. If so, 100 total properties will also count default google provided properties also and there is no way to add public custom properties anymore over 30, right? @Iamblichus

Comment: Hi @ErikaKay I'm not sure what you mean by `default google provided properties`. But yeah, you cannot have more than 30 public custom properties.